# 1966 Suzuki K11 Oil Change

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, two-stroke

Got a old suzuki that's running and working just fine. I got the fuel ratio for the bike which is 20:1 this a two-stroke. What I'm trying to figure out is the oil for the bike. Normally do 10w30 or 10w40 in old honda's but didn't know if this bike ran like some old bike that just use the same fuel for inside the engine. Found some specs here: http://www.rhuss.cncfamily.com/1965_k11.htm

Wanted to confirm before going ahead with this.

Comment: 1966 has a Posi-Lube injector pump. 1965 is likely premix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tracked down the official Suzuki service manual printed in 1966, this is what they say...

Under 6-2:

`The K10P & K11P engine requires no gas/oil mixture as fuel unlike conventional 2-stroke engines. The engine's moving parts such as the crankshaft. Crankshaft bearings, con-rod , piston and cylinder wall are positively lubricatedby fresh oil which is separately pressurce-delivered from the variable displacement oil pump. This unique force oil system is called "Suzuki Posi-Force Lubrication"`

`Put gasonline only in the fuel tank and lubrication oil in the oil tank. Recommend fule for the K10P & K11p, as for all all Suzuki motorcycles is a premium grade gaslone. Recommended oil for the "Suzuki Posi-Force Lubrication" system is a quality grade 2-stroke oil`

Be sure to use one of these prescribed oils:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best choice for any two stroke air cooled engine is an oil specifally designed for that application.  Two stroke oils are designed to burn cleanly and leave no ash behind which is what you want.  Look for API "TC" and also JASO FA and FB ratings.

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JASO_M345, they didn't establish until 1994.

Comment: That's true but today's two-stroke oils are better than what was available in 1966.  The lubricate better and smoke less.